# Shell - How can I split a line of text into fragments using SED?

Tags: shell, sed

I got a output from a command and it is something like this `2048,4096,8192,16384,24576,32768`.

I want to split it into 6 different files but only the numbers, not the commas e.g
The initial text: `2048,4096,8192,16384,24576,32768` be split into: `2048` to the file A, `4096` to the file B, `8192` to the file C and so on.

That output follows this rules:

1. There are always 6 spaces, separated by commas
2. The numbers are always from 3 to 5 "length" (I don't know the proper English word)
3. As I told you, commas doesn't interest me because I'm going to do mathematical operations with those numbers

I tried to delete the last X numbers but didn't get a way to "detect" a comma so the operation can stop. 
Is it possible using SED?

Comment: This appears to be mistagged -- comments make it clear the OP is asking for code that will run on Android, and is using `#!/system/bin/sh` as their shebang; thus, code needs to be written for POSIX sh, not bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following requires on *no* commands external to a POSIX-compliant shell (such as busybox ash, which you're most likely to be using on Android):

```
csv=/system/file.csv
IFS=, read a b c d e f <"$csv"
echo "$a" >A
echo "$b" >B
echo "$c" >C
echo "$d" >D
echo "$e" >E
echo "$f" >F
```

This *does* assume that the files to be written (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F`) are all inside the current working directory. If you want to write them somewhere else, either amend their names, or use `cd` to change to that other directory.

Comment: This is it. Perfect. Just needed to `cd /system`

Comment: The simpler the better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure sed is the right tool for that.

With a simple Bash script:

```
IFS=',' read -ra val < file.csv
for i in "${val[@]}"; do
   echo $i > file$(( ++j ))
done
```

It writes each values of you csv into `file1`, `file2`, etc. :

- The `read` command assigns values from `file.csv` to array variable `val`.
- Using loop, each value is written to file.

Just make sure you have write permissions in the current directory. If not, change the redirection (eg: `> /dirWithWritePermissions/`).

Comment: I'm using Android now, I tried: #!/system/bin/sh

mount -o rw,remount /system
csv=/system/file.csv

IFS=',' read -ra val < $csv
for i in "${val[@]}"; do
   echo $i > file$(( ++j ))
done but is returning error Read-only filesystem at line 10. The file contains 9 lines. So please explain more that bash script...

Comment: "Read-only filesystem" means you can't write to the output file because it's not in a writable location. Nothing to do with the script's correctness; no other program could do that either. (You remounted `/system` read-write, but is your destination location there?)

Comment: @LennoardSilva, `/bin/sh` (or `/system/bin/sh`) is not guaranteed to be bash. Please be more specific about which shells you're asking for in how you tag your questions -- `read -a`, as used in this answer (correctly, per how you tagged the question) is a bashism, and may not be available on POSIX sh.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed, bash and parallel):

```
parallel --xapply echo {1} ">>" part{2} :::: <(sed 's/,/\n/g' file.csv) ::: {1..6}
```

This "zips" together two files reusing the shorter file as necessary.

N.B. Remember to remove any `part*` files before applying this command otherwise those files will grow (`>>` appends).

Comment: The OP is on Android; hence, what they have is Busybox, a non-GNU toolchain. There's also no perl there, hence no GNU parallel.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There is a GNU Parallel package for Termux on Android and has been since 2015 https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/parallel

Answer (score 0):

```
declare list_of_files=(fileA fileB fileC fileD fileE)
readarray a <<< $(sed 's/,/\n/;{;P;D;}' <<< '2048,4096,8192,16384,24576,32768')
for i in ${a}; do
  echo $i > "${list_of_files["$((num++))"]}"
done
```

Explanation:

- `s/,/\n/` substitutes every comma with a newline
- `{` starts a command group
- `P` prints everything in the pattern buffer up to the first newline
- `D` Detetes everything in the pattern buffer up to the first newline and then restarts the current command group
- `}` ends the command group

EDIT:
Let's say you want to copy the information into `/system/file` but want to have every number in its own row:

```
$ sed 's/,/\n/;{;P;D;}' < /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree > /system/file
```

This will create a *new* file `/system/file` that will contain the formatted output.

EDIT: even shorter would: `sed 's/,/\n/g'`, which works just by replacing every comma with a new space (which is done by the g at the end).

Also note that while `sed` is a nice to tool to use (you gotta love it for its confusing language and commands...), the better and faster way is to use the [bash built in `read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins).

Comment: I used cat /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree to get that 2048,4096,8192,16384,24576,32768. I can pass this value to a file and store for later use (/system/file,  I'm on Android) but how can I use your script with that? I tried to adapt but got no result.

Comment: ...this works, yes, but why in the world would you do it? `IFS=, read A B C D E` will read the string into multiple variables far more efficiently; the OP may *ask* for `sed`, but I can't conceive of a good reason to use it.

Comment: ...actually, on `/bin/sh` it may not work, since it's depending on array support as currently written.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question/answer community. The OP asks for something, the OP should get an answer that best fits that question.

Comment: Your new answer solved my problem, but I did some modifications. First I tried that code, the terminal got frozen so I killed it, went back to /system and the file "file" was with 200Mb+. So I tried to make a variable with  `cat /sys/module...`. Didn't work as well. So I did this:

Comment: `#!/system/bin/sh  
mount -o rw,remount /system  

file=/system/placeholder  
cat /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree | busybox tee -a $file  

busybox sed 's/,/\n/;{;P;D;}' < $file > /system/file` and got that values separated by line breaks with no comma into the /system/file

Comment: @hgiesel, how this Q&A site decides, as a community, to answer questions that explicitly request to use the wrong tool for the job is a topic for discussion for meta. Personally, I find myself a follower of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321931/14122 -- note the "tragically misguided" case where the OP's request is *not* to be given deference. We're not quite there in this instance, but we're not as far as you think -- `for i in $(...)` has lots of potential hidden bugs (if your input contains a `*`, for instance, you get a list of files in the current directory injected into your output).

Comment: ...also, this answer proposes code directly contrary to accepted best practices: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think the best way to encourage learning is to enable using the wrong tools. Remember how your mother always told you ***The best way to live is to not smoke and eat your vegetables!***? Even though that might be nice advise, the best way to learn is to try something, see how that might not be the best way, looking for a better answer and do that instead.

Comment: Learning by experience *takes time*, and is sometimes very, very expensive. One of the learning experiences I once witnessed is multiple TB of backups of logs used for customer billing deleted due to a shell script inadequately quoting (and a buffer overflow putting an "impossible" value into a filename). Learning best practices some means other than by counterexample and consequence would have been much, much cheaper in that case.

Comment: @hgiesel given your theory that we should all try smoking rather than listening to the best advice from doctors with decades of experience on the subject, do you have any suggestion for if/when we should give it up again? Once we get lung cancer maybe? Should we all be handing our kids scissors to run with? The point is it's outrageously absurd to suggest that the best way to learn is to try things that have been proven to have negative consequences rather than listening to and learning from the experience of others.

Comment: I don't believe this is the place for such a discussion. I'm just saying that there's a bigger learning effect when you try alternatives for yourself and decide for yourself what's better for you, rather than others deciding for you.